# match closest value pair

Tags: php, regex

how would one find the closest match string to another string

so for example

string1:val1 ... string1:val2 .... string2:val3 ...

should capture the closest string1 to string2 which would be "string1:val2"

- string1 can appear any number of times.
- the in between characters can be anything

Comment: See [`.*"title":(.*)"value":`](https://regex101.com/r/Ctu9h8/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew there coud be unlimited # of first string preceding

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew last "title":" " which is closest to "value":" "

Comment: Is it the inner title /value you're look for?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could have any characters after "title" including " so that wont work. think of it as a general question

Comment: @m.r. - what if string is `"title":"text2" asjdsjsd "value":"val1" "title":"text3"`?

Comment: You mean *escaped* quotes? Ok, see [this demo](http://ideone.com/g5gcRy) with `'/.*"title":"([^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*)"/i'`. Or I think my first comment suggestion is quite valid - http://ideone.com/34P8Jz.

Comment: @GurV so then should get closest title to "value" in your case, "title":"text2"

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew looking for a general answer. i'll update question to clarify

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970). What sln suggests is a tempered greedy token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is something like `(?s)"title":(?:(?!"title":).)*?"value":".*?"`

```
 (?s)                    # Dot-all modifier
 "title":                # Literal 'title'
 (?:                     # Group start
      (?! "title": )          # Negative assertion, not 'title' ahead
      .                       # Ok, grab this chakracter
 )*?                     # Group end, do 0 to many times
 "value":" .*? "         # Until 'value' is found
```

Output

```
  **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 73 , len 39 ) 
 "title":"text2" asjdsjsd "value":"val1"
```

Comment: what is (?s) for? can you explain what this does. thanks

Comment: It's a regex construct called an _Inline Modifier_. The `s` means Dot-all = (the . )matches any character including newlines.

Comment: and what is (?! would be helpful if you could explain the steps if possible

Comment: Added comments.